# On back pressed from any activity the exit app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have placed the back button in the action bar for navigating between activities
and I want to set on back pressed of the mobile phone from any activity user exits the app.

I can define this explicitly in each activity but I want to write it in one place to avoid writing the same piece of code in each activity.
Is there some way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You should create `BaseActivity extends Activity` with your logic about back button and where you need the same behaviour simply `extends BaseActivity`

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a tag in manifest for all activities like,

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.shoppingapp.AddNewItems"
android:label="" 
android:noHistory="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

First Create BaseActivity like below:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static String ACTIVITY_FINISH_ACTION = "my.activities.finish.action";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    registerBroadCastReceiver();
}

private BroadcastReceiver mFinishReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(ACTIVITY_FINISH_ACTION)) {
            finish();
        }
    }
};

private void registerBroadCastReceiver() {
    registerReceiver(mFinishReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTIVITY_FINISH_ACTION));
}

private void unRegisterBroadCastReceiver() {
    unregisterReceiver(mFinishReceiver);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(BaseActivity.ACTIVITY_FINISH_ACTION);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unRegisterBroadCastReceiver();
}
```

}

Then extend your each activity with `BaseActivity` and on your back button press, send the broadcast like below:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(BaseActivity.ACTIVITY_FINISH_ACTION);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: I have created BaseActivity and override my onBackPress() method ,   public void onBackPressed() {
  
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(BaseActivity.ACTIVITY_FINISH_ACTION);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }  ,  but it's not working !

Comment: Do I have to change  String ACTIVITY_FINISH_ACTION = "my.activities.finish.action" , according to my project?

Comment: On pressing the back button it is just going back to the previous activity, but I want to close the app

Comment: ACTIVITY_FINISH_ACTION  is just a string, no need to change it anyhow.

Comment: edited BaseActivity, overrided onBackPressed() method. Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

To exit the app from any activity by giving warning to user,

I have implemented BaseActivity class as below:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String ACTIVITY_FINISH_ACTION = "my.activities.finish.action";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        registerBroadCastReceiver();
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mFinishReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(ACTIVITY_FINISH_ACTION)) {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Warning")
                        .setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(BaseActivity.this);
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();

            

            }
        }
    };

    private void registerBroadCastReceiver() {
        registerReceiver(mFinishReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTIVITY_FINISH_ACTION));
    }

    private void unRegisterBroadCastReceiver() {
        unregisterReceiver(mFinishReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unRegisterBroadCastReceiver();
    }
}
```

Extend this BaseActivity class to each class and override onBackPressed() method as below:

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(BaseActivity.ACTIVITY_FINISH_ACTION);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your BaseActivity. It will work as expected for each activity that will extend BaseActivity.

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    finishAffinity();
    finish();
}
```